# Which software ppa to use after applying LTS Enablement Stacks

Tags: kernel, ppa, hardware-enablement-stack

I have applied the LTS Enablement Stacks on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
I am now running 12.04.5 with kernel 3.13.0.36 (so I guess these are the same Kernel than those currently on 14.04 LTS?).

In my list of repository, I have not changed the repositories to use and left them on "ubuntu precise main". But for example for Virtualbox I have now to use the latest version to get virtualbox to work...

Shall I do the same for the ppa of other software and change the ppa to Raring or Trusty(14.04) main?
Or is it best to stick to ppa for Precise?